# What is meaning of linear systems in Pearl, Glymour, Jewell

Tags: structural-equation-model, causality

In "Causal Inference in Statistics" by Pearl, Glymour and Jewell page 122:
"In linear systems, where reversal of transitions amounts to negating the signs of their effects, we have the standard additive formula TE=NDE+NIE".

What does linear systems mean in this context?
Is it exactly the same as the path diagrams of structural equation modeling that are a system like this:

```
X=Ux
Z=0.2*X + Uz
Y=0.1*X + 0.25*Z + Uy
```

where Ui are random normal disturbances

I ask because I have created random data of that SEM form, but my resulting NIE matrix is not symmetrical (neverminding the opposite sign of the reverse transition), so I may not have calculated it right.

Answer (score 0):

"Linear system" means that the functions in the structural equation are linear and therefore reversing an effect is the same as subtracting the original effect.

In general, `TE = NDE-NIE_r` where the subscript indicates the reversal of the NIE contribution. If the system is linear, this is the same as `TE = NDE+NIE` (note the change of sign and missing subscript).
In effect, you are summing up the paths Treatment->Outcome and Treatment->Mediator->Outcome.
(See [Page 464 eq 12](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r389-reprint.pdf) for the context of the question.)

In your simulation, you first need to define a treatment to be able to compute the quantities `NIE = E(Y_{0, M1)-Y_{0, M0))` and `NIE_r = NIE = E(Y_{0, M0)-Y_{0, M1))`. Note that both are scalars, not matrices.
Consider the example of X=1 under Treatment and 0 otherwise. Here, `NIE = mean((0.25*(0.2+Ux) + Uy) - Uy)` while `NIE_r = mean(Uy - (0.25*(0.2+Ux) + Uy))` and you can see how the sign is simply flipped.